C# how to loop through a shared property of multiple static classes
im currently developing a simple console game and i've been stuck on how to implement the collision properly. when the player collides with an object, something should happen (for example, if the player collides with an item, they should collect it). i've got this part down, but my code feels too repetitive and i'd like someone to take a look at it
i have a file Potion.cs, as well as other similar files that are meant to represent the items in the game:
static class Potion
{
    public static string ItemName { get; } = "POTION";
    public static string Description { get; } = "A peculiar beverage that mends any wound.";
    public static string Art { get; } = @"./data/art/potion";
    public static char Appearance { get; } = '+';
    public static ConsoleColor Color { get; } = ConsoleColor.Blue;
    public static bool Discovered { get; set; } = false;
}

and a snippet of the main method:
//the player collides with an item
if (map[playerPositionLeft][playerPositionTop] == Potion.Appearance)
{
    items.Add(Potion.ItemName);
    Potion.Discovered = true;
}

else if (map[playerPositionLeft][playerPositionTop] == Revive.Appearance)
{
    items.Add(Revive.ItemName);
    Revive.Discovered = true;
}

//... and so on and so forth for every other item

i imagine theres a much cleaner and more readable way to do this, so please let me know. i was thinking i could somehow loop through the Appearance property of every class, but then how would i loop through the classes themselves?
minor edits:
i chose to make Potion a static class because i don't see the need to create objects for them. i used the classes themselves as a way to store their respective item data, which generally never changes except for the Discovered property. however, like i said, im sure there's a better way to do this and im open to feedback. thanks
im currently on c# 12

There is no way to iterate over static properties. Better would be to declare a class GameObject with properties Name, etc., and make Potion an instance of it.

@RaymondChen how could i access every Appearance property shared by the children of GameObject?

List<GameObject> AllObjects = new List<GameObject> { Potion, Wand, Cloak }, then you can foreach (var o in AllObjects) { ... }

@RaymondChen got it! so i made potion, along with every other item class inherit from a gameobject class, and then i added those to a list, which allowed me to access their properties. tysm!

You can create an array of the class names you are interested of, so this will be an array of strings.
Then, you can loop your array, like:
foreach (string s in myClassNames) {
    Type t = Type.GetType(s);
    if (map[playerPositionLeft][playerPositionTop] == t.GetProperty("Appearance").GetValue(null, null)) {
        items.Add(t.GetProperty("ItemName").GetValue(null, null));
        t.GetProperty("Discovered").SetValue(null, true);
    }
}

The code above is using reflection to get the class whose name is s and then uses a combo of GetProperty (to get the property by name), GetValue (to get the value of a property) and SetValue (to set the value of a property).
